# Get Storyboard identifier of Container View from child View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have multiple container views on MacOS (Xcode/AppKit) which all embed segue to the same PistonViewController class, as in below image.
[image]

Each container view has an identifier, e.g. "multiPiston1, multiPiston2", etc...
I would like the PistonViewController has an array of buttons with IBActions. On button action, I would like to get the identifier of the correct Container View, so that I know in which view the action is taking place.

I have tried the following in the PistonViewController class:

```
class pistonViewController: NSViewController {
...
    @IBAction func pistonClick(_ sender: NSButton) {
    if self.view.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "multiPiston1")
    
    if self.parent.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "multiPiston1")
    
    if self.parent.view.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "multiPiston1") 
} }
```

All of them, upon printing, give the wrong identifiers. So how do I find this identifier?

EDIT: Alternatively, each embed segue is separate - if I could somehow get the identifier of the embed segue, then I could also find out which Container View is being used.

EDIT: (my understanding of) web of relationships.

View Controllers: MainController -> PistonViewController

NSViews: MainControllerView -> ContainerView -> PistonView (view of PistonViewController)

Comment: Have you tried `self.view.superview.identifier`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Restoration ID for each Container on Storyboard and use like this

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(self.restorationIdentifier)
    
}
```

}

[Set Restoration ID here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGqlz.png)

Comment: restoration ID is only for ViewControllers... ContainerView is a View (NSView)

Answer (score 0):

NSViewControllers and NSViews live in separate domains, so to speak. So since the ContainerView is not a ViewController, to solve this problem it was necessary to communicate via NSViews.

Subclass the ContainerView and set identification attributes in the subview, i.e. the NSView of the PistonViewController:

```
class ContainerView1: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }
    override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
         //print("hello???")
        print(self.subviews)
        let rail = self.subviews[0] as! pistonRail
        rail.container_id = self.identifier?.rawValue
    }
}
```

The view subclass of the PistonViewController:

```
class pistonRail: NSView {
    var container_id: String?
   
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }
}
```

Access the NSView attributes of the PistonViewController through self.view:

```
class pistonViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBAction func pistonClick(_ sender: NSButton) {
            
            let pistonRail = self.view as! pistonRail
            print("view id: " + (pistonRail.container_id ?? "no"))
        }
}
```